# Index Match Match - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two tables in Google Sheets.

**Table 1** is a list of contacts arranged vertically with multiple records appearing for each city.

In **Table 2**, I'd like the city name to appear only once and the contacts to be displayed horizontally.

My first guest was to use `Index Match Match`, however I'm unable to retrieve contacts 2 and 3 - an error appears saying `Function INDEX parameter 3 value 2 is out of range.`

Any ideas on how to solve this problem and is `Index Match Match` the best method?

[image]

Comment: Excel & Google sheets can play differently so decide which you are using.

Comment: Which ever one is the path of least resistance - issue is the same on both with my current approach

Comment: Well, done lots of index with match on here so you can check those out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is happening because you are using a `MATCH()` function in the column parameter of the `INDEX()` function. `MATCH()` returns a row index of where the value is found, not a column.
While it is possible to solve with an INDEX/MATCH method, another way you could solve this is with `VLOOKUP`:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(vlookup($A$12:$A$14,if($B$3:$B$8=B$11, {$A$3:$A$8,$C$3:$C$8}, false),2,FALSE)))`

This formula can be placed in cell `B12` and copied across the columns.

[image: ex]